# Deleting a project on CodePlex

Tags: codeplex

How do I remove/delete a project of mine from Codeplex.com?

Comment: You might want to check Codeplex's web site. Perhaps they have FAQs related to that.

Comment: Try here: http://codeplex.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=1539

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Edit: It is possible now, to delete a project without contacting the CodePlex team*

See [Delete a Project](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Start%20a%20Project#Delete):

> - Signed in as a project owner click on the project's **Settings tab**
> - Navigate to the bottom of the page
> - Click the **Delete** button. If you choose to delete your project, this action is destructive and **cannot be undone**.

Answer (score 2):

You are now able to delete projects directly from your project settings page. You can learn more [in the documentation.](https://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Start%20a%20Project&referringTitle=Documentation#Delete)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the FAQ now there is a 'Delete This Project' button(http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CodePlex%20FAQ#DeleteProject).

Comment: No, the FAQ says that an unpublished project has a Delete this button. You should contact first to unpublish it.

Comment: From [FAQ](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CodePlex%20FAQ#DeleteProject): `If you have already published your project, then use the Contact Us page to request that your project be unpublished so that you can delete it. 
Your project's pages should now have a "Delete This Project" button at the top. Click this and your project will be deleted.'` **First** contact then **after** the button will exists.